# Structure memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, c, memory, structure, instance

As we know that memory of structure is allocated when its variable is defined(or when creating an instance).

Now

```
struct Programmer {
int skills;
int problemSolved;
};

int main(){
Programmer me;//Here the memory will be allocated but in what 
              //format(discrete or continuous block of memory)?
me.skills = 10;
me.problemSolved = 2000;
return 0;
}
```

**Is the memory allocated to structure instance or variable is in continuous blocks(as in array) or in discrete block of memory ? If yes then Why?**

Comment: Yes it is, but remember there's padding (not always).

Comment: All you can be guaranteed in a structure is that the members will be allocated in the order that they are declared.  The compiler is allowed to insert "padding" bytes, as an example for alignment purposes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews-- there is also a guarantee that there will be no padding at the beginning of a `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory allocated for a `struct` is contiguous. From [§6.2.5 ¶20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20) of the C11 Draft Standard:

> A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of
>   member objects....

But, there may be padding within the storage allocated for a `struct`, according to [§6.7.2.1 ¶15](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15):

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

And, from [6.7.2.1 ¶17](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p17):

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

Comment: Yes and I can also avoid the padding by #pragma pack, btw Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The structure is allocated on the stack, in one contigous block of memory (probably 64 bits in this case).  It is allocated when the function is called (unless your compiler does something tricky).

All instance variables are allocated on the stack (although it's not specified how they're allocated in the standard, this is how all compilers do it).  The reason is, when you call a function recursively, it will get a new stack frame for more variables.  That way, if you have a variable "me" on the stack, and you call main() from within main(), you end up with a second "me" variable in the second stack frame.  When the second "main()" returns, the stack frame is released for other future calls.

Comment: Reminder:  There is no requirement for the variable to be located on a stack.  There is no requirements for a stack.

Comment: Agreed.  (a) it's not specified in the standard, (b) compiler optimizations can remove it or put it elsewhere